# (javafx) I'm currently making an app which requires people to create an account, how can i make sure the texts fields aren't null?

Tags: java, if-statement, javafx, fxml

I have some code written but it doesn't exactly work but it explains what I want it to do.

I think I've narrowed it down a little, it says I can't compare strings with == or !=, what is an alternative to this? I have changed my password fields to .equals() so they work properly, however I don't know an alternative for !=.

Controller class:

```
@FXML
        private void handleCreateAccountContinue(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
            if(NewUsernameFieldC.getText()!=null && NewPasswordFieldC.getText()!=null && NewPasswordFieldC.getText()==NewPasswordConfFieldC.getText() 
                    && NewEmailFieldC.getText()!=null && NewSteamlinkFieldC.getText()!=null){
                //ADD INFO TO DATABASE
                System.out.println("correct input");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("incorrect input");
            }
        }
```

any ideas? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can´t check with null. You should check for empty String.
Also you should compare with equals not with "==" since String is an object. you will be comparing references and is not what you want. You want to compare text.
that´s why you should use equals.

NOTE: when you try to check if is not equals you just need to use the "!" at the beginning as I did it.

```
@FXML
private void handleCreateAccountContinue(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    if(!NewUsernameFieldC.getText().isEmpty() && !NewPasswordFieldC.getText().isEmpty() && NewPasswordFieldC.getText().equals(NewPasswordConfFieldC.getText()) 
            && !NewEmailFieldC.getText().isEmpty() && !NewSteamlinkFieldC.getText().isEmpty()){
        //ADD INFO TO DATABASE
        System.out.println("correct input");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("incorrect input");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you're looking for blank text fields by comparing the input to null. You should instead be comparing the input to "" to see if nothing was entered. Hope it helps!

Comment: this almost works but when there is nothing in one or more of the text fields I still get the first if statement returned and not the else statement

Comment: Ah I see what you were doing. I see how you responded above. That always works but if you wanted you could've used || instead of negating all the && sections.

Comment: oh yea that's very true and that would make more sense, I'm going to change that right now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my issue, instead of doing this

Wrong code example:

```
@FXML
        private void handleCreateAccountContinue(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
            if(NewUsernameFieldC.getText()!=null && NewPasswordFieldC.getText()!=null && NewPasswordFieldC.getText()==NewPasswordConfFieldC.getText() 
                    && NewEmailFieldC.getText()!=null && NewSteamlinkFieldC.getText()!=null){
                //ADD INFO TO DATABASE
                System.out.println("correct input");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("incorrect input");
            }
        }
```

You would do this:

```
@FXML
    private void handleCreateAccountContinue(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        if(!NewUsernameFieldC.getText().equals("") && !NewPasswordFieldC.getText().equals("") && NewPasswordFieldC.getText().equals(NewPasswordConfFieldC.getText()) 
                && !NewEmailFieldC.getText().equals("") && !NewSteamlinkFieldC.getText().equals("")){
            //ADD INFO TO DATABASE
            System.out.println("correct output");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("incorrect input");
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Never compare `String` with == or !=. To check if `String` is empty use `.isEmpty()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I always check the length of the text

```
If(NewUsernameFieldC.getText().length > 0)
{
  //the text field is not null
}
```

Comment: You go also check out ControlsFx fields validation.